# Question Regarding Integral Solution

Tags: integration

For context, I'm a college student studying Integral Calculus for the first time.

When I solve $\int \:\:\frac{secx\cdot \:cos\left(2x\right)}{sinx+secx}dx$ by hand, I get $\ln\left(\sin\left(2x\right)+2\right)+c$. When I put the integral into Wolfram Alpha, I get $\log\left(\sin\left(2x\right)+2\right)+c$. When I evaluate a definite integral with the bounds of 0 to 5, I get the same answer by hand and via Wolfram Alpha, even though Wolfram Alpha gives me a different anti derivative.

Thoughts?
Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Sorry, where is the difference in the antiderivatives? Wolfram|Alpha will use log to denote the natural logarithm, so it looks like the antiderivatives are the same.

Comment: Use this too:https://www.integral-calculator.com/ I found this pretty helpful when I was doing Calc 2. It's not perfect but it may help.

Comment: @E__. May be not perfect but it gave me several times solutions i was not obtainable by WA.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Wolfram Alpha is using log with no base attached to it to mean the natural logarithm. These are the same antiderivatives.